# virt-manager USB 2.0 problem

Tags: usb, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I have an Ubuntu 12.04 64bit with QEMU/KVM & virt-manager 0.9.4 (latest compiled from source) installed

my problem is that all guest windows machines does not recognize usb2.0 ports:

1. windows xp recognizes all usb devices as USB 1.0
2. windows 7 recognizes usb controller as USB1.0 but does not recognize all usb devices (yellow mark)

my system is fully up-to-date and I have recently upgraded virt-manager from 0.9.1 to 0.9.4 and also upgraded to virtinst 0.600.3 and virt-viewer 0.5.4

The problem also existed in 0.9.1.

Comment: Is there a feature in 0.9.4 that you need which isn't in 0.9.1?  Installing from source makes it impossible for someone to exactly replicate you setup to try and help.

Comment: 0.9.1 supported usb 2.0.  have you followed this: http://www.linux-kvm.com/content/virt-manager-adds-support-usb2 ?  you have to specify a usb 2.0 device

Comment: i looked at the mailing list and it looks like there was more than one way to implement usb 2.0 support and there was some disagreement on how it should be implemented.  have you tried adding the physical usb2.0 hub (echi) as the shared device instead of the virtual device?

Comment: okay, last shot is it needs hardware virtualization or some manual xml editing about the vm in question.  i saw some command-line examples on forcing the usb2.0 virtual device in, but i think it might require hardware virtualization to work.  my laptop doesn't have that, so i can't take the testing any further

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was [Here](http://www.linux-kvm.com/content/virt-manager-adds-support-usb2#comment-5437)

Issue the command `virsh edit testmachine` to open the XML, where **testmachine** is your machine name seen in virt-manager, and added the following lines to the `<devices>` section:

```
<controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-ehci1'>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x07' function='0x7'/>
</controller>
<controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci1'>
  <master startport='0'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x07' function='0x0' multifunction='on'/>
</controller>
```